# How to deploy node + react App on goDaddy shared hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy react and nodejs app on GoDaddy hosting but its just showing nodejs output,

I am serving my build folder like this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
    app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

still react app isn't showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem with this.
i just removed the if condition and its started working fine because the if condition `process.env.NODE_ENV`doesnt work here..:)